# Scaling text on canvas in Firefox looks horrible

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

It seems that Firefox does pretty bad job at scaling text on canvas. Check this out:

```
ctx.font = "12pt arial";
ctx.fillText("Today, however, the Scottish contributed", 10, 20);

ctx.scale(3, 3);
ctx.font = "4pt arial";
ctx.fillText("Today, however, the Scottish contributed", 10/3, 20);
```

Result:

[image]

Here's comparison to Chrome, both with scaling. The latter is doing just fine here.

[image: Firefox vs. Chrome]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvMGaK

You don't have to be a rendering nut to notice the difference. **Is this a known issue? How can I fix it?**

Comment: Easy fix is to scale down not up.

Comment: Can't repro on... Android. What if you disable hardware acceleration? Anyhow, bugzilla has a quite powerful search engine and mozilla's one should be able to tell you if it is a known issue. If it isn't feel free to open an issue, and don't forget to include your specs.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Firefox 59.0 and this does not seem to be an issue anymore, so I would simply suggest updating your browser to solve this problem. However, per the mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText), if a 4th parameter max-width is not specified for fillText, then it will try to use the smallest possible width, which may be causing some issues. If the issue still persists in your browser version, then you may want to try changing the letter spacing. This can be done by saying something like:

```
ctx.canvas.style.letterSpacing = "5px";
```

This is a very hacky solution though as it involves changing the letter spacing of the canvas element itself and although it works, it is not actually in the documentation and therefore is not required to work on all browsers. The best solution probably would just be to keep your browsers updated and/or use a different font.

Comment: I get this on 60 "dev edition" as well as 59 "standard".

Contrary to what you say, the docs explain that interesting things happen only when maxWidth is set. Either way, I tried both the letterSpacing and maxWidth ideas, neither makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was initially just testing on my Mac, which appears to not have this issue. However, after spinning up an Ubuntu VM I was able to duplicate your problem, which makes me believe this could be a platform-specific issue. Regardless, as I mentioned at the end of my answer, other fonts such as Palantino appear to render just fine after being scaled. I realize this might not be the best solution to your problem, but if a specific font isn't critical, this could solve a headache.